# How do I select a build in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, build

I tried to publish the app to Apple Store Connect. Normally there is a "+" button but I don't see one right now because Apple have updated iTunes Connect and introduced a bug. How can I get around this bug and select a build to submit my app to the App Store.
I cannot choose the build to Submit for review.

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded a new version a few days ago, and everything seems to be working just fine on iTunes Connect. Could you please make sure you're following the steps below:

1. First create a build from Xcode with a specific version number (for instance 1.3.0), archive and upload to iTunes Connect. Wait a few minutes for the build to process.
2. Once the build has finished processing, make sure it's available on iTunes Connect by navigating to My Apps/Activity/iOS Builds. If everything is okay you should see your new build "Version 1.3.0" here.
3. Now before you can change the build, and this may be the step you're missing, **you need to add a new version of your app for submission, via "+ Version or Platform"**. This number should match the build you uploaded earlier (1.3.0).
4. Then just select the newly created version of your app on the left menu, and you will have the option to select the new build you want to use for this version in the "Build" section.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The Step 2 in @user13639548 answer confused me even more because I didn't find activity/ios builds.

What solved the problem however was changing the versin from 1.1 to 1.1.0. and then also waiting 3-5 more minutes until the + button appears again.